# How should I handle questions that do not specify an answer in a specific language?

Tags: discussion, answers, languages

I periodically browse the [soundcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/soundcloud) tag and found this question today:

[How to get track ID from URL using the SoundCloud API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289927/how-to-get-track-id-from-url-in-soundcloud-using-api)

The author of the question did not specify what programming language he wanted an answer in, so I just provided a high-level answer on what endpoints to hit to get track information.

How should the questions be handled? Should I have posted a comment and asked the user for more information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The author of the question did not specify what programming language he wanted an answer in, so I just provided a high-level answer on what endpoints to hit to get track information.

That's totally correct! Without being asked for examples in a specific language, laying out the structure of the API, and pointing out the parts to be used, is just what you should do.

> How should such questions be handled?

For APIs that can be targeted similarly in many languages (such as the HTTP API in question), no further action is required. They can be answered without problems - as you just did.

Only if the usage of the API deviates a lot depending on the application language, more information needs to be given in the question. RegEx questions see this kind quite often.

> Should I have posted a comment and asked the user for more information?

Yes, you can always do that. Now that you know the OP is using PHP, you can extend your answer with a more specific example - if you want.